# New has many :through association - best way to add data to the through model as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

Say I have a cat collection where I want to store some information about the relationship between the cat and the collection. I setup my models like so:

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collection_cats
  has_many :cats, through: :collection_cats
  ...

class CollectionCat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :cat
  ...

class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collection_cats
  has_many :collections, through: :collection_cats
  ...
```

Adding cats to the collection is easy:

```
collection = Collection.new
collection.cats << Cat.new(name: 'Mog')
collection.save

puts collection.cats.first.name # -> 'Mog'
```

Now, what is the best way to add a new cat to the collection and also at the same time add some information about the relationship (like who added the cat to the collection)?

```
collection = Collection.new
cat = Cat.new(name: 'Mog')
collection.collection_cats << CollectionCat.new( cat: cat, collection: collection, added_by: 'John')
collection.save

puts collection.cats # -> []
```

ok, I understand why collection.cats is empty - I've only added the relationship, but I'm sure there's a better way to do all this AND with collection.cats returning the new cat without doing any model reloads.

What is the correct/best/simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using nested forms to achieve the result and most easily with [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem.

Comment: I'd like to know the best way to achieve this outside the view layer

Comment: Following your path this works `collection = Collection.new(name: "Spanish")`,  `cat = Cat.new(name: "Pedro")`, `collections.cats = cat`, `collection.collection_cats << CollectionCat.new( cat: cat, collection: collection, added_by: 'John')`, `collection.save`. Maybe you are looking for a shorter system?

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo: `collections.cats << cat` is correct and not `collections.cats = cat`

Comment: ok but I think you also mean collection.cat not collections.cat but anyway you'd land up with two associations: one from the collection.cats << cat and another from collection.collection_cats << CollectionCat.new... etc)

Comment: I made some search but I did not find any shorter way. I do not now your purpose but to be less verbose an helper can help :) `def new_association(collection_name, cat_name, added_by)
  collection = Collection.new(name: collection_name)
  cat = Cat.new(name: cat_name)
  collection.cats << cat
  collection.collection_cats << CollectionCat.new( cat: cat, collection: collection, added_by: added_by)
  collection.save
 end`, then call from console: `helper.new_association("British", "Paul", "Me")`

Comment: True but you'd still land up with [] for collection.cats until you'd refreshed the model. It feels like you should be able to add the model (cat) along with the through model (collectioncat) at the same time AND have collection.cats returning the new cat.

Comment: I do not understand, after the transaction is committed `puts collection.cats` prints out `<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Cat id: 1, name: "Meowy", created_at: "2016-02-22 21:34:06", updated_at: "2016-02-22 21:34:06">]>`, not []. Try with `collection.cats.map(&:name)`, that's printing out `["Meowy"]`